# QWebEngine hinders github navigation by default

Tags: qt, qt5, qwebengine

I'm working on a web browser and without changing any QWebEngineSettings, github can't load the necessary javascript.

QWebEngines javascript output when visiting github

```
The Content-Security-Policy directive 'worker-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled.
Uncaught TypeError: this.toggleAttribute is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: this.toggleAttribute is not a function
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined
...
```

And so on, I've tried setting

```cpp
settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, true);
```

And made sure they are enabled, yet without any success. Do anyone happen to know which security policy I have to change to make github work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from Qt 5.9.9 to 5.15.0 solved the issue.